# Run ansible role for just created LXC container

Tags: linux, ansible, devops, lxc

I'm configuring a bunch of LXC containers through ansible, and got stuck.
I had set up host, created some containers via `lxc_container` module, and now I need to do some actions on these containers.
I could use `container_command` from `lxc_container`, but it doesn't provide any checking mechanism and looks like a tool for some simple actions. But I need to perform complex set up on these containers, and I wish to use ansible for that.

In other words, I need to perform actions (roles) on all "submachines" for each host, and these submachines are created dynamically.

I have 2 solutions in my mind:

1. Have 2 separate ansible playbooks, one running on control machine
   and the second copied to each host and executed from within first
   playbook. Sounds clumsy.
2. Dynamically create host groups with newly created containers, and then run container-setupping play for each group.

First solutions is clumsy as it is, but may sound like good opportunity to use ansible-pull, which I don't want for simplicity reasons.

Second solution is the one I can't make work because I don't have SSH access to these containers from control machine, and because I don't know how to run plays for dynamically generated group hosts.

There should be a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I thought, at my org we did choose to go with #3

1. **connection plugin**: ansible can use a different connection for your guest; we did fiddle with a lxc_attach plugin but it wasn't as reliable as ssh.
   Basically we would create a container and create a new host in the inventory with the option 'ansible_connection' set.
2. **certificates**: we have a certificate authority set up, copy the CA public key to the machine with a 'lxc-attach ...' and make sshd trust it.Then you can login on the guest with your public key and your user certificates. Ansible will go nuts because the host is not known, use the module 'add_host' to set the appropriate options for ssh to login without warning and continue working. We call this approach the nursery and it is not idempotent.

   - name: update container user ca key
     shell: lxc-attach -n {{ vm_name }} --clear-env -e -- bash -c "grep -F 'ssh-rsa {{ user_ca_key }}'     /etc/ssh/user_ca.pub || echo 'ssh-rsa {{ user_ca_key }}' > /etc/ssh/user_ca.pub"
     register: update_user_ca_key
     changed_when: "update_user_ca_key.stdout != 'ssh-rsa {{ user_ca_key }}'"
   - name: trust user ca key
     shell: lxc-attach -n {{ vm_name }} --clear-env -e -- bash -c "grep -F 'TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/    user_ca.pub' /etc/ssh/sshd_config || echo 'TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/user_ca.pub' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_    config"
     register: trust_ca_key
     changed_when: "trust_ca_key.stdout != 'TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/user_ca.pub'"
3. **certificates everywhere**: this is madness and I really like the approach.
   Exactly as with #2 copy the CA public key on the machine, then copy the container host certificate and sign it with your CA, place the certificate on the container. Now you can connect to your container with ssh using your private key and user certificate. Because your local machine is trusting the CA ansible will not scream at you if it connects to an unknown host (your container) if it exposes a host certificate.
4. **Just copy everything**: you are using ansible so you need python and ssh, just create a template container manually and clone it instead of creating a new one.

I would really like to have choosen #2 but now we are stuck with #3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the container_command to copy the host's SSH key (where the ansible is running)  to container's authorized_keys folder. After that you can access to the container if you use it in the host file:

```
NAME hostname=HOSTNAME ansible_ssh_host=IP_ADDRESS  ansible_connection=ssh  ansible_user=USER   ansible_ssh_extra_args="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
```

The extra args need that the authentication don't use known_hosts. You have two way copy your key to the container.

1. Use the shell module after the lxc_container module, and copy the host's id_rsa.pub to /var/lib/lxc/CONTAINER_NAME/rootfs/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys but before you need to use this in the container_command:

   container_command: yum -y install openssh-server && ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N ""
2. If you mounted a folder from the host to the container you can take to this folder your .pub key and in the container_command you can copy it to the authorized_keys.

These are not too elegant solutions but I spend days searching for better, but didn't find.

Comment: I don't have access from control machine to container because of network settings, not because of keys. Also, take a look at ssh agent forwarding (`-A`), this might save you from copying keys. BTW I'm currently looking at ssh jump hosts, this might work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the second choice (run a playbook for all newly created LXC in their own hosts group) work with SSH-proxyCommand by which you enable your Ansible management host to SSH-connect to the containers via the target host (bastion or jump host) where you run the lxc_container module to create them.